# How can I use LastInsertId to insert a value from another table

Tags: php, mysql, oop, xampp, crud

So I have two tables order_manager and order.
The goal is to insert the order_id from order manager into the user_order table.

Im unsure how to use the variable $order_id in my controller in this scenario. Ive attempted using the InsertLastId as i thought this would be the best solution. But still cant wrap my head around how I can grab its value in the controller.

Here's my Controller

```php
  
    if($artworks -> confirm_order($full_name,$phone,$address,$email));{//this table has a primary key of order_id thats auto increments
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $values)

  {     
        $title=$values['title'];
        $price=$values['price'];
        $quantity=$values['quantity'];
        $artworks -> new_user_order(/*$order_id,*/$title,$price,$quantity);//foreign key of order_id
  }
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
    }
```

here's my model

```php
    public function new_user_order($order_id,$title,$price,$quantity){
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user_orders(order_id,title,price,quantity) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$order_id,$title,$price,$quantity]);
        //$order_id = $this->connect()->LastInsertId();
        header("location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way to do it would be

```
$order_id = $stmt->insert_id;
```